# Groovy XML Parser Dollar Sign in Attribute $

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, dollar-sign

I am using XMLParser to parse an xml document that has the following structure:

```
<Tag>
    <SubTag att1="some.directory.structure.ClassName$InternalClass" att2="value2"/>
</Tag>
```

I am trying to store the value of att1 in a String with:

```
def att1Value = root.Tag[0].iterator().toList()[0]['@att1']
```

However, when I read att1Value, it's value is "some.directory.structure.ClassName".  Is Groovy treating the $InternalClass as a variable?  How do I capture the whole value of att1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
xml = '''<Tag>
    <SubTag att1="some.directory.structure.ClassName$InternalClass" att2="value2"/>
</Tag>'''

root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

att1value = root.SubTag[0].@att1
```

Gives me the result

```
"some.directory.structure.ClassName$InternalClass"
```

Comment: It was some other problem. Sorry to mislead.